# Plotting points on a map with colors depending on their value, using coordinates

Tags: r, plot, ggmap

I am new to R and trying to plot some points in different colors on a map, concerning their values and using coordinates.
Data (df) looks as follow:

> longitude latitude value
>
> -9.41667 
>   147.5333
>   0.32
>
> -9.41667
>   147.5333
>   0.56
>
> -9.33333
>   147.2333
>   0.78
>
> -19.23948
>   146.8044
>   0.53
>
> -35.26409
>   149.0835
>   0.49
>
> -24.79456
>   147.7503
>   0.74
>
> -27.49773
>   152.7428
>   0.73

I used `ggmap::get_map`:

```
MAP <- get_map(location='australia', zoom=4, maptype = "terrain", source='google', color='color')
```

and then tried the following:

```
ggmap(MAP) + geom_point(data = df , aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, color= value))
```

It is only plotting the values, but how can I plot the values in different colors on the map I got?

Comment: Please post the code that you used already with the getMap function.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "plot the values in different colors"? Do you mean you want each point to be a different color (red, blue, yellow, green, etc.)? Or you want to change the existing color (I assume it is blue?) to something else (e.g. red)? You may find http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_colour_continuous.html or http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html helpful.

Comment: Ideally i would plot the values in one color with different shades, like 0 as a light blue and 1 as the darkest blue and the values between with the according color shades.
To get the map i used  the function get_map(location='australia', zoom=4, maptype = "terrain", source='google', color='color')

Comment: Hi @Ella, all code should go in the question, not in comments. You can edit your post to add additional information. For now, I've edited the post to add your `get_map` code

Comment: You also seem to have the latitude and longitude switched in your dataset. Look at the map you get from `ggmap`: the longitude values are around 130, 140; the values in the same range are labeled incorrectly as latitude in your data. So the points don't show up at all by running your `ggmap` code above.

Answer (score 1):

The comments from camille are pretty much on point, you just need to reverse your lat and long values but otherwise you are pretty much there.

```
library(ggmap)

df <- data.frame(
longitude = c(-9.41667,-9.41667,-9.33333,-19.23948,-35.26409,-24.79456,-27.49773),
latitude = c(147.5333,147.5333,147.2333,146.8044,149.0835,147.7503,152.7428),
value = c(0.32,0.56,0.78,0.53,0.49,0.74,0.73))

MAP <- get_map(location='australia', zoom=4, maptype = "terrain", source='google', color='color')
ggmap(MAP) + geom_point(data = df , aes(x=latitude, y=longitude, color= value))
```

Yields this map:

[image]